# Can't read from a file even though it is there - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading a file to a destination, and I can confirm that the file is there, in fact I can check whether that file is read-only or writable, but I am getting an error when I try to show the context of this file : `"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Documents” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it`. Anyone had this issue before? It's driving me nuts because I can't even track down the location on my computer because I am using my iPad to run the app. Would be grateful if someone could help me out.

Code snippet where I check for a file :

```
let documentsURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]


let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(documentsURL))
{
    print("FILE AVAILABLE");
}
else
{
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
}

print(documentsDirectoryPath)

if checkValidation.isWritableFileAtPath(documentsURL) {
    print("File is writable")
} else {
    print("File is read-only")
}


var newarray = [Int]()

do{

    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: documentsURL as String,
        encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    print(data)

    print("i am at the do statement")

     newarray = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.map{
        Int(String.init($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))!}


    print(newarray)


}
catch let error { 
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Your `documentsURL` points to the "Documents" *directory*, not to a file ...

Comment: @MartinR why is that this piece of code `if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(documentsURL))` gives me that the file is available at that path?

Comment: Because the directory exists. (A directory is in many aspects treated like a file, but you cannot read from or write to it.)

Comment: @MartinR hmm, thank you for this. Do you know how I could point to the actual file in that directory in this case?

Comment: You need to know the file name and use `documentsURL .URLByAppendingPathComponent(yourFileName isDirectory: true)`

Comment: isDirectory : false or just ommit it

Comment: @MartinR @zcui93 I might be doing this completely wrong, so correct me please if so. When I am downloading the file, I am actually using this method `let localFilePath = (documentsDirectoryPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(selectedFile.filename)` to save it at that location. The issue arises when I need to retrieve this file in another controller. Could this be because I am not passing that file as an argument and therefore I am unable to locate it in that folder?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. The path used for saving the file is the same the you have to use for opening the file again (where should  that information come from otherwise??).

Comment: @MartinR well i was just thinking that I could just follow the path to the file and see if the file at that path exists and manipulate it. I guess i was wrong

Comment: @MartinR actually, quick question, so its not possible for me to locate this file in another controller? I mean I just have to do everything i want to do with that file in the method where i save it?